# Customize Perl Markdown to recognize note paragraphs with title (newbie to perl)

Tags: perl, markdown

I know nothing about Perl, but I really just need to make this one tiny change to markdown syntax. So I apologize that I'm ask a very basic question.

I want to create a customized markdown to do this

```
<div class="note">
<b>My note title</b>
My note texts 
</div>
```

I found [this great post](http://www.pingtrip.com/weblog/2008/04/adding-custom-tags-to-markdown) that is able to create `div` with note class, with syntax below:

```
~? This is a Note Block ~?

~! This is a Warning Block ~!
```

however, I'd like to be able to specify a title for the note, by enclosing the title in some symbol. Something like below:

```
~? #Title#
This is a Note Block ~?
```

Below is the **Perl customized class** from the post

```
sub _DoNotesAndWarnings {
    my $text = shift;

    $text =~ s{
            \n~([\!\?])      # $1 = style class
            (.+?)           # $2 = Block text
            ~[\!\?]         # closing syntax
        }{
            my $style = ($1 eq '!') ? "Warning" : "Note";
            "<div class=\"$style\">" .  _RunSpanGamut("<b>$style:</b> \n" . $2)  .  "</div>\n\n";
        }egsx;

    return $text;
}
```

How should I modify this code? Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: You can't just use the multiline example and add your title directly ?

Comment: Could you point me to the example? I'm very new to all this. I did try to modify this code, but didn't success at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want seems to be:

```
sub _DoNotesAndWarnings {
    my $text = shift;

    $text =~ s{
            \n~([\!\?])      # $1 = style class
            (?:\s*\#([^\#]+)\#\s*)? # $2 = title, optional
            (.+?)           # $3 = Block text
            ~[\!\?]         # closing syntax
        }{
            my $style = ($1 eq '!') ? "Warning" : "Note";
            my $title = $2 || $style;
            "<div class=\"$style\">" .  _RunSpanGamut("<b>$title:</b> \n" . $3)  .  "</div>\n\n";
        }egsx;

    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Thank you very, very much! If you don't mind explain to me, how was the `$1` to `$3` variables declared or defined?. It had been an absolutely a mystery for me!

Comment: You're welcome! Every time you use a regular expression with a capturing group (parenthesis `()` but without a sequence questionmark-colon after the opening parenthesis, i.e., **not** `(?:)`), the string matched by that capturing group goes into the `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc. variable, in the order of the opening parenthesis (the first opening parenthesis delimits `$1`, the second `$2`, etc.) all automagically declared and ready to be used. I recommend that you read http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html (in that order) so you will not fly so solo anymore.